# Integral with series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

How do I represent this integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{10}{10+x^4} dx$$

as a series so that I can calculate with an error of less than $10^{-5}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$\frac{1}{1 + \frac{x^4}{10}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{4n}}{10^n}$$

where $|x| < 1$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{10}{10+x^4} = \frac{1}{1-\left( \frac{-x^4}{10} \right)} = \frac 1 {1-r} & = 1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots \\[6pt]
& = 1-\frac{x^4}{10} + \frac{x^8}{100} - \cdots
\end{align}
Integrating term by term from $0$ to $1$ gives
$$
1 - \frac 1 {50} + \frac 1 {900} -\cdots
$$
Since the terms alternate in sign and get smaller, and approach $0$, the error after each term is always smaller in absolute value than the next term.